# Why does re.sub in Python not work correctly on this test case?

Tags: python, regex

Try this code.

```
test = ' az z bz z z stuff z  z '
re.sub(r'(\W)(z)(\W)', r'\1_\2\3', test)
```

This should replace all stand-alone z's with _z

However, the result is:

' az _z bz _z z stuff _z  _z '

You see there's a z there that is missing.  I theorize that it's because the grouping can't grab the space between the z's to match two z's at once (one for trailing whitespace, one for leading whitespace).  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it does that is that you get an overlapping match; you need to not match the extra character - there are two ways you can do this; one is using `\b`, the word boundary, as suggested by others, the other is using a **lookbehind assertion** and a **lookahead assertion**. (If reasonable, as it should probably be, use `\b` instead of this solution. This is mainly here for educational purposes.)

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!\w)(z)(?!\w)', r'_\1', test)
' az _z bz _z _z stuff _z  _z '
```

**`(?<!\w)`** makes sure there wasn't `\w` before.

**`(?!\w)`** makes sure there isn't `\w` after.

The special `(?...)` syntax means they aren't groups, so the `(z)` is `\1`.

---

As for a graphical explanation of why it fails:

The regex is going through the string doing replacement; it's at these three characters:

```
' az _z bz z z stuff z  z '
          ^^^
```

It does that replacement.  The final character has been acted upon, so its next step is approximately this:

```
' az _z bz _z z stuff z  z '
              ^^^ <- It starts matching here.
             ^ <- Not this character, it's been consumed by the last match
```

Answer (score 7):

If your goal is to make sure you only match `z` when it's a standalone word, use `\b` to match word boundaries without actually consuming the whitespace:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\b(z)\b', r'_\1', test)
' az _z bz _z _z stuff _z  _z '
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to avoid capturing the whitespace. Try using the 0-width word break `\b`, like this:

```
re.sub(r'\bz\b', '_z', test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
test = ' az z bz z z stuff z  z '
re.sub(r'\b(z)\b', r'_\1', test)
```