# Use regular expressions to replace overlapping subpatterns

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regular expression substitution:

```
input=re.sub( r"([a-zA-Z0-9])\s+([a-zA-Z0-9])" , r"\1*\2" , input )
```

I use the regular expression on the string `"3 a 5 b"`.

I get back `"3*a 5*b"`.

I am thinking I should get back `"3*a*5*b"`.

So somehow my regular expression substitutions are interfering with each other.

What can I do to get the result I want, other than iterative runs of the regular expression?

Comment: input = re.sub(" ", "*", input) - this gets you what you want

Comment: No, @PurityLake, it doesn't. That would produce incorrect replacements in the string `"3 /a 5! b"`

Comment: sorry only acted on the information i was given, I only thought you wanted to replace spaces with "*" character

Comment: At least in my mind, @PurityLake, that information is clearly conveyed by the character grouping `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: See also: [Why does re.sub in Python not work correctly on this test case?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4295591/5025060).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use a [lookahead assertion](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), `(?=...)`, so as not to eat up the second pattern:

```
In [33]: re.sub( r"([a-zA-Z0-9])\s+(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])" , r"\1*" , '3 a 5 b')
Out[33]: '3*a*5*b'

In [32]: re.sub( r"([a-zA-Z0-9])\s+(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])" , r"\1*" , "3 /a 5! b" )
Out[32]: '3 /a*5! b'
```

Comment: And **remember**, when you change a (group) to a (?=lookahead), the (group) no longer exists.  That is why there is no \2 in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not always the best tool for the job when using Python. For the case you describe above, Python offers a much simpler, more readable, and more maintainable method:

```
>>> s = "3 a 5 b"
>>> '*'.join(s.split())
'3*a*5*b'
```

Comment: A nice answer - unfortunatelly, the O.P. updated his needs in the comments. This does answer the original question, though.

Comment: The character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]` clearly excludes replacement of the space when it falls between a variety of characters while your suggested answer does not.

Comment: Ah yes, the post has been updated I see. Given the new information, a lookahead assertion does indeed sound like the best answer to me.