# Best way to remove specific words from column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I'm working with a huge set of data that I can't work with in excel so I'm using Pandas/Python, but I'm relatively new to it. I have this column of book titles that also include genres, both before and after the title. I only want the column to contain book titles, so what would be the easiest way to remove the genres?

Here is an example of what the column contains:

```
Book Labels
Science Fiction | Drama | Dune
Thriller | Mystery | The Day I Died
Thriller | Razorblade Tears | Family | Drama
Comedy | How To Marry Keanu Reeves In 90 Days | Drama
...
```

So above, the book titles would be Dune, The Day I Died, Razorblade Tears, and How To Marry Keanu Reeves In 90 Days, but as you can see the genres precede as well as succeed the titles.

I was thinking I could create a list of all the genres (as there are only so many) and remove those from the column along with the "|" characters, but if anyone has suggestions on a simpler way to remove the genres and "|" key, please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an enhancement to @tdy Regex solution. The original regex `Family|Drama` will match the words "Family" and "Drama" in the string. If the book title contains the words in `gernes`, the words will be removed as well.

Supposed that the labels are separated by " | ", there are three match conditions we want to remove.

1. Gerne at start of string. e.g. `Drama | ...`
2. Gerne in the middle. e.g. `... | Drama | ...`
3. Gerne at end of string. e.g. `... | Drama`

Use regex `(^|\| )(?:Family|Drama)(?=( \||$))` to match one of three conditions. Note that `| Drama | Family` has 2 overlapped matches, here I use `?=( \||$)` to avoid matching once only. See this problem [[Use regular expressions to replace overlapping subpatterns]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301832/use-regular-expressions-to-replace-overlapping-subpatterns) for more details.

```py
>>> genres = ["Family", "Drama"]

>>> df

#                       Book Labels
# 0      Drama | Drama 123 | Family
# 1      Drama 123 | Drama | Family
# 2      Drama | Family | Drama 123
# 3  123 Drama 123 | Family | Drama
# 4      Drama | Family | 123 Drama

>>> re_str = "(^|\| )(?:{})(?=( \||$))".format("|".join(genres))

>>> df['Book Labels'] = df['Book Labels'].str.replace(re_str, "", regex=True)

# 0       | Drama 123
# 1        Drama 123
# 2        | Drama 123
# 3    123 Drama 123
# 4        | 123 Drama

>>> df["Book Labels"] = df["Book Labels"].str.strip("| ")

# 0        Drama 123
# 1        Drama 123
# 2        Drama 123
# 3    123 Drama 123
# 4        123 Drama
```