# Re.sub overlapping python

Tags: python, regex

In python, I tried to use re.sub to substitute all "&&" in a string with some letters. However, I only have to substitute those which have spaces on both sides, so "&&&" and " &&x" must not be substituted. But if I substitute " && " (so the spaces are included in the substituted string, then in " && && " (with only one space between them), only the first one is substituted. 
Like this problem: [Why does re.sub in Python not work correctly on this test case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295591/why-does-re-sub-in-python-not-work-correctly-on-this-test-case)

I tried to use the solutions in that answer, but \b or \b simply didn't work, as in the program stopped substituting even the " && ", and the other solution:

`lines=re.sub(r'(?<!\w)(&&)(?!\w)',"and", lines)`

Though it worked for " && && " and didn't substitute in " &&x ", it still did substitute " &&& " and " '&&' ", both of which it shouldn't.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You just need to lookahead and behind for a space: `lines=re.sub(r'(?<=\s)(&&)(?=\s)',"and", lines)`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookahead:

```
lines = re.sub(' &&(?= )', ' and', lines)
```