# Python: re.sub skips every other match for multiple consecutive occurrences of same pattern

Tags: python, regex

I was intending to replace all occurrences of stopwords in a document using re.sub(). The first thing I tried was the obvious one:

```
re.sub('how|to', 
       '@', 
       'how to do this thing') 
#Replacing with @ for easy identification of replaced words
```

This returns, as expected, `'@ @ do this thing'`. However, this would also match subwords, not necessarily whole words. So for example

```
re.sub('how|to', 
       '@', 
       'how to do this thinghowto'
```

returns `'@ @ do this thing@@'`. Since I want to match whole words only, I tried

```
re.sub('(^|\s)how($|\s)|(^|\s)to($|\s)',
       '@',
       'how to do this thinghowto')
```

and it returns `'@to do this thinghowto'`. It looks like the pattern didn't match for ' to '. To see whether this is the case, I test out:

```
re.sub('(^|\s)how($|\s)|(^|\s)to($|\s)',
       '@',
       'how to to how how howtohowto to how')
```

and get `'@to@how@howtohowto@how'`. The pattern seemingly skips over every other match, but it does match only whole-word occurrences. (In case you're familiar with ML parlance, it looks like this has a perfect precision, but only 50% recall.) Why is this happening, and what could I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Use whitespace boundaries, `r'(?<!\S)(?:how|to)(?!\S)'`. Lookarounds are not consuming text, so the consecutive occurrences will get matched. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295591/why-does-re-sub-in-python-not-work-correctly-on-this-test-case) to see the example of the technique to replace consuming patterns with non-consuming.

Comment: (BTW, not my downvote, I think this question is good as a "signpost".)

Comment: Yeah I made sure to write this so that if someone were searching like me they found it relatively easily. And the downvote is okay I guess, the question does seem a bit dumb after seeing the explanation. Anyhow, thanks for the help!

Comment: BTW, if anyone else sees this in the future, a much simpler solution is using the word boundary special character, \b: 

```re.sub ( '\\bhow\\b|\\bto\\b', '@', text)
```

Comment: There is a [canonical dupe target for word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863066/python-regular-expression-match-whole-word), too.